# how to delete row in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, repository, sql-delete

I write this in my JpaRepository

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Backlog b WHERE b.code = ?1")
void deleteBacklog(String code);
```

and this is my method :

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public Integer deleteBacklog(String code) {
        try {
            backlogRepository.deleteBacklog(code);
            return IReturnedValues.DELETE_BACKLOG_SUCCESS;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
```

I got this in the console:

```
Hibernate: delete from backlog where code=?
```

but when I check my database I still have the row.
How i call my method:

```
if(code == null || code == "") {
            //user exist, check if the code is valid or not
            response=ResponseEntity.ok(IReturnedValues.DELETE_BACKLOG_TOKEN_VALIDE);
}else {
                        //check if exist a backlog with this code 
                        List<Backlog> backlog = backlogMetier.findByCode(code);
                        if(backlog == null) {
                            response= ResponseEntity.ok(IReturnedValues.DELETE_BACKLOG_CODE_NOT_EXISTE);
                        }else if(backlog != null){
                            try {
                                //delete the backlog
                                retour=backlogMetier.deleteBacklog(code);
                                response= ResponseEntity.ok(retour);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                return ResponseEntity.ok(responseClassMax);
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
```

this is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Backlog {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long idBacklog;
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Utilisateur userBacklog;
    private Date creationDate;
    private String title;

//getters & setters
//constructors

}
```

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show how you call `deleteBacklog(String code)` method and code of your `Backlog` entity.

Comment: @matejko219 okay

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query(value=""DELETE FROM Backlog b WHERE b.code = :code")
  void deleteBacklog(@Param("code") String code);
```

It seems Query error, try above code.

Comment: the same problem

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   @Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    long deleteByTitle(String title);
}
```

test this method

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void whenDeleteFromDerivedQuery_thenDeletingShouldBeSuccessful() {
    long deletedRecords = repository.deleteByTitle("The Hobbit");
    assertThat(deletedRecords).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

Comment: is there any way with JpaRepository?